# Windows Store: textbox inside flipview, cannot dismiss SIP keyboard when lost focus

Tags: windows-store-apps, on-screen-keyboard, flipview

I am using a full-screen flipview to allow a background to rotate behind a set of inputs. if you tap the input textbox, the SIP keyboard appears.

however, tapping outside of the textbox does not dismiss the keyboard as expected. I finally realized it is because of the flipview. I verified this by adding a 250 margin around the flipview. if i tap in the area covered by the control it still doesn't dismiss, but if I tap the areas covered by the margins (that is, outside the flipview) the SIP does dismiss as expected.

I tried setting IsTabStop to false and IsTapEnabled to false for the flipview, but the SIP still remains active unless i tap outside the flipview.

since we need the flipview to be full screen, I need to know if there is a way to disable the control so that it closes the keyboard.

can this be done? which property or event on the flipview can I leverage to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

aha, by handling the "tapped" event I did the old trick of disabling and enabling the flipview and sure enough the keyboard dismissed!